# Rendering reports from multiple folders in BIRT

Tags: eclipse, tomcat, birt

I have multiple folders containing reports under /report folder in the BIRT WebViewer. I would like to be able to deliver these reports on the web.

Directory structure is as follows

```
- BIRTWebViewer
  - report
    - Finance
    - Sales
    - Marketing
```

I have tried adding the folder to the report parameter value passed to the frameset

```
frameset?__report=/Finance/BalanceSheet.rptdesign
and
frameset?__report=Finance/BalanceSheet.rptdesign
```

Neither of them seem to work.

Please suggest what is the best way to support rendering reports from multiple folders.

TIA

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume these reports all load fine if they are in the main "report" directory?  In other words your application is properly set up to load from report?

I would try:  `frameset?__report=./Finance/BalanceSheet.rptdesign` (note the dot before the path)